# Computer temporarily freezes and then resumes

Tags: hard-drive, freeze

This happens on ALL operating systems (7, Ubuntu, etc.).

What happens is everything for 1-3 seconds becomes unresponsive, I then hear what sounds like my other internal hard drive 'spinning up', and then viola everything is responsive again.

Note: Already ran SMART tests, no issues at all.

I think issue is that the HDD spins down and when need it gets 'turned-on' (OS settings turn off HDD's after 20 mins of inactivity) and because my pagefile is on the other HDD it causes OS to temporarily freeze.

Need more tips, and insight.

Thanks

More info:
Running Quad CPU, 4GB RAM, Intel SSD, GT 240.

Comment: "OS settings turn off HDD's after 20 mins of inactivity"  You're right.  This will cause that.  *Change the setting.*

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that power settings turn off the HDD after 20 minutes. To fix simply disable this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this with "greeen" drives like some Western Digital ones.  Exactly as you describe.  Once the drive spins up, all is well.

In my case, it was external drives and talking to WD support provided no solution.  It is by design and if the OS or app is trying to access the drive that has powered down, you wait.  Not sure if internal device can be more fully managed.

Comment: I'm fairly sure drive is not green drive: http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=20b92d0ca8dce110VgnVCM100000f5ee0a0aRCRD#tTabContentOverview